# "mirror" elements in a list

Tags: java

> Write a method mirror that doubles the size of a list of integers by
>   appending the mirror image of the original sequence to the end of the
>   list. The mirror image is the same sequence of values in reverse
>   order. For example, if a variable called list stores this sequence of
>   values:
>
> `[1, 3, 2, 7]`
>
> and we make the following call:
>
> `list.mirror();`
>
> then it should store the following values after the
>   call:
>
> `[1, 3, 2, 7, 7, 2, 3, 1]`
>
> Notice that it has been doubled in size by
>   having the original sequence appearing in reverse order at the end of
>   the list. You may not make assumptions about how many elements are in
>   the list. Because adding these elements might overrun the capacity of
>   the underlying array, you may need to call ensureCapacity to enlarge
>   this array.
>
> Assume you are adding to the ArrayIntList class with following fields:
>
> ```
> public class ArrayIntList {
>     private int[] elementData;
>     private int size;
>
>     public void add(int value) { ... }
>     public void add(int index, int value) { ... }
>     public void ensureCapacity(int capacity) { ... }
>     ...
>
>     // your code goes here
> }
> ```

What improvements can I make to help on my future coding? Interested in knowing if there are other ways to tackle this question, and if the way I solved the problem is safe? This code interacts with the [ArrayIntList.java](https://practiceit.cs.washington.edu/problems/shared/ArrayIntList.java) class.

```
public void mirror() {
    if (size != 0) {
        int limit = size * 2;
        this.ensureCapacity(limit);
        size = limit;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
           elementData[(limit - 1) - i] = elementData[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is good code, because it does what it says on the tin. I do have two remarks:

The `this.` in `this.ensureCapacity(limit)` isn't necessary. Some people swear by adding it anyway, so it's a matter of style.

The other remark is that you loop over twice as many elements as needed because you set `size` to `limit` before looping. You can hold off until after:

```
public void mirror() {
    if (size != 0) {
        int limit = size * 2;
        this.ensureCapacity(limit);
        //size = limit; // [!] moved to below >>>
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
           elementData[(limit - 1) - i] = elementData[i];
        }
        size = limit; // [!] <<< moved from above
    }
}
```

That's all. Good code.